# actualizar un campo total factura con la información del detalle

Tags: mysql

Estoy tratando de actualizar el campo `billTotal` en la tabla `tor_bill` de acuerdo con la información de detalle en `tor_bill_detail`. Hasta ahora puedo actualizar poniendo el id del registro. lo que quiero hacer es que cuando se agrege un nuevo registro a `bill_detail` se actualice el campo `billTotal` en la tabla `bill`, pasandole el id que debe actualizar.

```js
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `tor_bill_detail_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `tor_bill_detail` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 UPDATE `tor_bill` 
    SET `billTotal`= (select sum(billDetailTotal) from tor_bill_detail)
    WHERE `billId`='1';
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    UPDATE tor_bill
      SET billTotal= (SELECT sum(billDetailTotal) 
                        FROM tor_bill_detail 
                        WHERE billId = NEW.billId
                     )
      WHERE billId=NEW.billId;
```

Toma en cuenta que podrías necesitar algo similar cuando se borren o actualicen los registros en billDetailTotal.

Comment: Hola Sal, he solucionado mi problema gracias a ti. Funciona perfectamente, ahora tomaré encuenta tu aporte y lo implementaré  par alos demás casos. muchas gracias.

Comment: el tigger no me sirve para cuando se elimine el registro de tor_bill_detail, ¿Necesito realizar algo diferente? ERROR 1363: There is no NEW row in on DELETE trigger

Comment: En lugar de NEW usa OLD.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que debes hacer es enlazar el id de la tabla **tor_bill** con el de la tabla **tor_bill_detail** en la subconsulta, para que así sepa a que referencias de la tabla de detalle debe hacer la sumatoria:

```
UPDATE tor_bill
SET billTotal = (SELECT SUM(billDetailTotal) 
    FROM tor_bill_detail 
    WHERE tor_bill.billId = tor_bill_detail.billId);
```

Con ello se actualizaran todos los registros de la tabla tor_bill.

Espero te sirva mi respuesta, saludos.

Comment: Rostan muchas gracias por tu ayuda, al parecer la solución qu planteas no me funciona, estoy añadiendo la clausula ´WHERE´  a la actualización y me genera éste error:  1054. La columna 'tor_bill_detail.billId' en where clause es desconocida 0.000 sec